# Is this a statue of a six-armed wooden Buddha?

Tags: statue

[image]

Please help me identify this statue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> "Buddha statues generally show a particular Mudra (a Sanskrit word) or hand gesture."

~ Cited from: [Buddha Statue Mudras](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Buddha-Statue-Mudras)

- Bhumi Sparsha Mudra
- Samadhi / Dhyana Mudra
- Abhaya Mudra
- Dharma Chakra Mudra
- Vitarka Mudra
- Vajira Mudra
- Uttara Bodhi Mudra

Apart from the above listed Mudras there can be a combination of two Mudras or a variation of a Mudra depicted in a statue of Lord Buddha. For example the below statue of Lord Buddha depicts a variation of Abhaya Mudra.

[image]

~ Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avukana_Buddha_statue#/media/File:Buda_de_Avukana_-_01.jpg)

Since the statue you've shown doesn't depict any of the known Mudras, there is a high possibility of being that is not a statue of Lord Buddha.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have never seen these types of hand gestures and I have found nothing even remotely close to this figure.

Answer (score -3):

Basically in all south Asian countries Buddhism & Hinduism are the same, which is why Buddhism & Hinduism do not coexist as major religions in any Asian country. At a time in history, the ruling classes chose one of them. Each religion shares the same ideas & images in the social or cultural contexrt. Thus multi-armed deities (e.g., Brahma & Vishnu), bodhisattva and Buddhas can be found in many places and will generally have the same meaning.

As for the picture, it looks Indonesian, possibly Balinese (but I could be wrong).

Comment: `which is why Buddhism & Hinduism do not coexist as major religions in any Asian country` In Singapore for example, surely, co-existent but readily distinguishable.

Comment: Singapore is a modern commercial centre; similar to a western colony; such as Australia